# Implementing simple probabilistic model with negative log likelihood loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, unsupervised-learning

First a quick disclaimer would be that I posted this question on Reddit, in the Deep Learning and Learning Machine Learning first, but I thought I might also request your expertise here too. Without further ado:

I am currently challenging myself on this year [Deep Unsupervised Learning Course of Berkeley University](https://sites.google.com/view/berkeley-cs294-158-sp19/home) and although I just started the warmup exercise of week 1, I am already having 'technical' difficulties.

The exercise in question is the "1. Warmup" in the following document: [Week 1 Exercises](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DtYllaV4Yk8ljgYcLBmdXNplEDTG6HT6/view). (My apologies as I am not familiar enough with Reddit formating to seemlessly include images.

In my understanding, we have a variable `x` which can take values from `1..100` which a specific probability of being sampled ( defined in `sample_data()` function).
The task is therefore to fit a vector of parameters `theta` which is passed to a softmax function, and is supposed to give the likelihood of a specific element `x_i` to be sampled. Namely, `theta_1` should the parameter which "bumps up" the soft-max value corresponding to the variable `x = 1` and so on.

Using Tensorflow, I think I was able to create such a model, but when it comes to training, I believe I am missing a crucial point as the program cannot compute gradients with respect to the `theta` parameters.

I would like to know if am not misunderstanding the task, and if there is any better method to achieve the result of the exercise.

Here is the code, where the failing par is located from the `# Computing gradients`.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Sampling function of the x variable provided in the exercise
    def sample_data():
        count = 10000
        rand = np.random.RandomState(0)
        a = 0.3 + 0.1 * rand.randn(count)
        b = 0.8 + 0.05 * rand.randn(count)
        mask = rand.rand(count) < 0.5
        samples = np.clip(a * mask + b * (1 - mask), 0.0, 1.0)
        return np.digitize(samples, np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 100))

    full_data = sample_data()
    train_ds = full_data[:int(.8*len( full_data))]
    val_ds = full_data[int(.8*len( full_data)):]

    # Declaring parameters theta
    w_init = tf.zeros_initializer()
    params = tf.Variable(
        initial_value=w_init(shape=(1, 100),
        dtype='float32'), trainable=True, name='params')


    softmax = tf.squeeze( tf.nn.softmax( params, axis=1))

    #Should materialize the loss of the model
    def get_neg_log_likelihood( inputs):
        return - tf.math.log( softmax)

    neg_log_likelihoods = get_neg_log_likelihood( softmax)

    dist = tfp.distributions.Categorical( probs=softmax, dtype=tf.int32)

    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

    for epoch in range( 100):
        minibatch_size = 200
        n_minibatches = len( train_ds) // minibatch_size

        # Running over minibatches of the data
        for minibatch in range( n_minibatches):
            # Minibatching
            start_index = (minibatch*minibatch_size)
            end_index = (minibatch_size*minibatch + minibatch_size)

            x = train_ds[start_index:end_index]

            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                tape.watch( params)
                loss = tf.reduce_mean( - dist.log_prob( x))

            # Computing gradients
            grads = tape.gradient( loss, params)
            print( grads) # Result: None
            # input()
            optimizer.apply_gradients( zip( grads, params))
```

Thank you in advance for your time.

PS: I mainly have a background in Deep Reinforcement Learning, therefore I can understand the various models used there ( policy, value functions ...), but I am trying to refine my grasp over the internals of the models themselves, namely in generative probabilistic models (GAN, VAE) and other unsupervised learning models in general ( RealNVP, Norm Flows, ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure nobody is gonna see this, but I thought I might as well bring some closure to this.

First of all, I calculated the gradients by directly deriving its expression from the negative log likelihood of the soft-max value, thus dropping the Tensorflow framework by the same occasion.

Although the results are a little bit under my expectations, the program was able to fit the model to a distribution somewhat similar to the empirical distribution of the sampled data. I guess this is due to the fact that just a 1 dimensional theta parameter vector is not enough to fully model the real data distribution, as well as the finite amount of sampled data.

An updated version of the code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

np.random.seed( 42)

def softmax(X, theta = 1.0, axis = None):
    # Shamefull copy paste from SO
    y = np.atleast_2d(X)
    if axis is None:
        axis = next(j[0] for j in enumerate(y.shape) if j[1] > 1)
    y = y * float(theta)
    y = y - np.expand_dims(np.max(y, axis = axis), axis)
    y = np.exp(y)
    ax_sum = np.expand_dims(np.sum(y, axis = axis), axis)
    p = y / ax_sum
    if len(X.shape) == 1: p = p.flatten()

    return p

if __name__ == "__main__":
    def sample_data():
        count = 10000
        rand = np.random.RandomState(0)
        a = 0.3 + 0.1 * rand.randn(count)
        b = 0.8 + 0.05 * rand.randn(count)
        mask = rand.rand(count) < 0.5
        samples = np.clip(a * mask + b * (1 - mask), 0.0, 1.0)
        return np.digitize(samples, np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 100))

    full_data = sample_data()
    train_ds = full_data[:int(.8*len( full_data))]
    val_ds = full_data[int(.8*len( full_data)):]

    # Declaring parameters
    params = np.zeros(100)

    # Use for loss computation
    def get_neg_log_likelihood( softmax):
        return - np.log( softmax)

    def get_loss( params, x):
        return np.mean( [get_neg_log_likelihood( softmax( params))[i-1] for i in x])

    lr = .0005

    for epoch in range( 1000):
        # Shuffling training data
        np.random.shuffle( train_ds)

        minibatch_size = 100
        n_minibatches = len( train_ds) // minibatch_size

        # Running over minibatches of the data
        for minibatch in range( n_minibatches):
            smax = softmax( params)

            # Jacobian of neg log likelishood
            jacobian = [[ smax[j] - 1 if i == j else
                smax[j] for j in range(100)] for i in range(100)]

            # Minibatching
            start_index = (minibatch*minibatch_size)
            end_index = (minibatch_size*minibatch + minibatch_size)

            x = train_ds[start_index:end_index]

            # Compute the gradient matrix for each sample data and mean over it
            grad_matrix = np.vstack( [jacobian[i] for i in x])
            grads = np.sum( grad_matrix, axis=0)

            params -= lr * grads

        print( "Epoch %d -- Train loss: %.4f , Val loss: %.4f" %(epoch, get_loss( params, train_ds), get_loss( params, val_ds)))

        # Plotting each ~100 epochs
        if epoch % 100 == 0:
            counters = { i+1: 0 for i in range(100)}
            for x in full_data:
                counters[x]+= 1

            histogram = np.array( [ counters[i+1] / len( full_data) for i in range( 100)])
            fsmax = softmax( params)

            fig, ax = plt.subplots()
            ax.set_title('Dist. Comp. after %d epochs of training (from scratch)' % epoch)
            x = np.arange( 1,101)
            width = 0.35
            rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, fsmax, width, label='Model')
            rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/2, histogram, width, label='Empirical')
            ax.set_ylabel('Likelihood')
            ax.set_xlabel('Variable x\s values')
            ax.legend()

            def autolabel(rects):
                for rect in rects:
                    height = rect.get_height()

            autolabel(rects1)
            autolabel(rects2)

            fig.tight_layout()
            plt.savefig( 'plots/results_after_%d_epochs.png' % epoch)
```

Picture of the final model distribution included for completeness. [Modeled vs Empirical Distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxfOJ.png)